# App Store Collection View Layout in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm planning to add a collection view like you can see in apple musics "browse" or the app store "apps" tab into my SwiftUI App. I tried with scroll view and stacks but it does not have this smooth movement effect. I figured that you could use NSCollectionView Layout and Diffiable Data Source in UIKit for this but I have no idea how to make it in SwiftUI. Any thoughts?

Heres is my code:

```
struct DiscoverPopularUsersViewPhone: View {

// MARK: Variables and Constants
@State private var fetchedUserAccounts: [UserAccount] = [UserAccount]()

var geometry: GeometryProxy

@State private var userResultsLoadState: LoadState = .inactive


// MARK: Body
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
        Divider()
            .padding(.horizontal, 18)
        
        HStack(spacing: 16) {
            Text("Popular Users")
                .font(Font.title3.weight(.bold))
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
            
            Spacer()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Popular Users")) {
                Text("View more")
                    .font(Font.callout.weight(.regular))
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 18)
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 12) {
                ForEach(fetchedUserAccounts) { account in
                    DiscoverUserGridItem(userAccount: account, size: (geometry.size.width - 18 * 2 - 12) / 2)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 18)
        }
    }
    .onAppear(perform: fetchPopularUsers)
}
```

}

The fetchPopularUsers method just fetches some user data

I am aware that there is not really a way to do this and it is not an error. But I want it a bit different even if this means I need a whole new approach.

You can see the snappy effect I want to achieve at the top of the App Store app. I could not include a video because it would be too large
[image: image app store]

Note: I would like the user to see that he is able to scroll so I think the PageTabViewStyle() modifier of TabView is also not an option

Comment: Can you include what you've tried and detail how the "smooth movement effect" is missing?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I updated my question. Hope this makes it a bit clearer

Comment: You still haven't elaborated on the "smooth movement effect". can you upload a gif or something?

Comment: I mean that it always stops at the center when you scroll

Comment: You can use diffiable datasource collection view for design. it will be better and easy